# Tangled lines in plotly line chart with dates in axis

Tags: r, plotly

im trying to create a line chart with dates in the x-axis using plotly but the lines I get are quite confusing like they go back and forth.

```
library(plotly)
date = c("2020-02-06", "2020-11-21", "2019-10-26", 
         "2020-09-20", "2020-01-11", "2019-09-15", "2020-08-03", "2019-02-05", 
         "2018-05-18", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-29", "2019-04-15", "2019-06-27", 
         "2017-11-29", "2017-12-01", "2019-04-04", "2017-11-28", "2018-11-29", 
         "2020-06-26", "2020-06-26") 
traffic.sp = c("28", "28", "20", 
                                                     "20", "22", "36", "36", "29", "0", "22", "23", "28", "28", "37", 
                                                     "26", "15", "39", "38", "22", "22")

df<-data.frame(date,traffic.sp)

fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~traffic.sp, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
fig
```

Comment: You could convert your `df$date` to dates (`as.Date`) and then `sort` before plotting. Would that give you want you are looking for?

Comment: yes it gives that

Answer (score 1):

This may be a better alternative that you can plug into plotly:

```
line <- df %>% 
  select(date,
         traffic.sp) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  ggline(
         x="date",
         y="traffic.sp",
         color = "steelblue")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

ggplotly(line)
```

Which gives you this:

[image]